# Is it possible to create an iOS build in CodenameOne without spending 99$/year?

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to create an iOS build in CodenameOne without Apple certificates? Can I install the .ipa file onto my iPad. I am a beginner and $99/y is just too much for merely getting my feet wet! Any workarounds?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that's about licensing/legal, not programming

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way Codename One works you can just test on Android and then purchase the $99 subscription when you are ready to move to iOS. You will need to buy it anyway regardless of whether you use xcode or not.

Apple didn't allow building on xcode without a certificate until version 7+ (we launched Codename One when version 4 was new). As a workaround we let people use our certificate but this meant they needed to jailbreak their iphone. This also created a lot of issues in our build process due to the complex set of scripts.

With version 7 Apple introduced the ability to build without the certificate but that only works if you have the device physically connected with a cable and have xcode & a Mac. Both of these aren't required for Codename One.

Comment: I saw a video of yours where you explained how to use codename one certificates. Is that not available anymore?

Comment: We now have a signing wizard which makes generating certificates MUCH easier. In the past you could just skip using certificates entirely but that was remarkably flaky. I did hundreds of videos so I have no idea if something old I did is still accurate as we refined the policy about a year ago to stop signing with our certificate. This was causing too many problems for developers and was unmaintainable.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, just install Xcode 7 from the Mac App store:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12

Once it downloads, run the app and go to the settings:

click Accounts
click the + in the lower left and add an Apple ID

enter a personal Apple ID, the one you use for the App Store is fine to reuse

When you build an app for iOS, connect the iOS device and choose that AppleID to sign the app when asked.

Comment: I do not have a mac?

Comment: Which programming language do you want to use?

Comment: i use codenameone java

Comment: Check this https://www.udemy.com/build-mobile-ios-apps-in-java-using-codename-one/  Lektion 7 
Deploying The App To An iOS Device